# How to configure nebula.integtest with gradle project's integration tests ( kotlin DSL)?

Tags: gradle, integration-testing, gradle-plugin, nebula-test

I wanna separate integration from unit tests in my gradle kotlin dsl project build ( the project itself written on java). There are many answers here how to configure source set etc.

But I came across [nebula.integtest plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/nebula.integtest) ( I hope it's well known plugin to don't blame me in promoting it)

But there is quite poor manual there, just:

```
plugins {
  id "nebula.integtest" version "8.0.0"
}
```

is it really all what need to be done? Which folder should contain integration tests then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the `README` of the project (emphasis mine):

https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-project-plugin#nebula-facet-plugin

> A corrolary from the Facet Plugin is a concrete Facet, this plugin provides one specifically for Integration Tests. By applying this plugin, you'll get an `integrationTest` Test task, **where sources go in `src/integTest/java` and dependencies can go into `integTestImplementation` and `integTestRuntimeOnly`** (which extend from the test SourceSet), with the 'check' task depending on the task. To apply the plugin: